# Reflect the Shape A in the line x = 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not that sure on how to reflect the Shape $A$. I know where the line $x = 1$ but I don't know which way to reflect it. To the left or up? Thanks, I know it seems a bit easy.

[image]

Comment: "reflect across the line" means that the mirror image of the shape will appear on the opposite side of the line.

Comment: ok, would the coordinates be $(-3,-1), (-5,-1), (-4,-2), (-4,-3), (-3,-3)$?

Comment: @HonkyHanka No, that would be reflection about $x=0$, not $x=1$.

Comment: @HonkyHanka You've drawn the red line at $x=1$, and the reflected shape should appear on the opposite side of this line. So for example, the point at $(3,-1)$ would travel to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: aah ok, so it needs to be on the opposite line of $x = 1$. $(-3,1), (-1,1)$ etc.?

Comment: @HonkyHanka Yes, the opposite side of the line you're reflecting through. (See my hint below too, if it helps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reflect anything around a line, as was pointed out by @rscwieb, makes the mirror image appear on the other side of the line. (Mirror image means an inverted shape).

Reflecting around $x=1$ never touches the $y$ coordinate, and the $x$ coordinate transforms - what was the distance to $x=1$ becomes the distance on the other side. In other words, if a point were at $x = \pi$, it's distance to $x=1$ was $\pi - 1$ so the new location is $\pi - 1$ to the *left* of $x=1$, i.e. $1- (\pi-1) = 2 - \pi$.

This gives you the idea, now try it yourself on the figure you drew.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to fold the graph on the line you're reflecting through, the original shape and the reflected shape should line up exactly.

This could apply to any line: vertical, horizontal or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subtract 1 from x-coordinates.
2. Switch sign of x-coordinates.
3. Add 1 to x-coordinates.

You can do all this with the matrix operations:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

You then multiply with this matrix from the right:

$$\begin{bmatrix}{\bf x}^T\\{\bf y}^T\\{\bf 1}^T\end{bmatrix}$$

$\bf x$ being column vector of x-coordinates

$\bf y$ being column vector of y-coordinates

$\bf 1$ being column vector of the value 1.